# PHP & SQL - Como obter informação especifica de cada usuario em uma table

Tags: php, html, sql

Olá, estou tendo problemas em coletar informações dos usuarios de uma database.

Na DB existem alguns usuarios, e os mesmos são exibidos em uma table.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu objetivo é que quando os nomes sejam clicados, ocorra um collapse que mostre toda a informação do usuario clicado, porém quando clicado ocorre o erro:

> undefined index

Segue o código:

```
<div class="row" id="realTimeContents myGroup">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="scrollable">
                <table class="table table-striped table-dark text-center">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>Nome</td>
                            <td>CPF/CNPJ</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM registro";
                            $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
                            $queryResults = mysqli_num_rows ($result);

                            if ($queryResults > 0) {
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              echo "<tr>
                                <td scope='row'>".$row['id']."</td>
                                <td><a class='' data-toggle='collapse' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='teste' href='#teste'?nome=".$row['nome']."&CPF=".$row['CPF']."'>".$row['nome']."</a></td>
                                <td>".$row['CPF']."</td>
                                </tr>";
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
        <!-- collpse user content -->
      <div class="collapse" id="teste">
        <?php
            $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_GET['nome']);
            $CPF = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_GET['CPF']);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM registro WHERE nome='$nome' AND CPF='$CPF'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
            $queryResults = mysqli_num_rows ($result);

            if ($queryResults > 0) {
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<td>".$row['nome']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['CPF']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['data_de_nascimento']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['numero_de_cadastro']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['CEP']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['numero']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['bairro']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['endereço']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['cidade']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['complemento']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['uf']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['telefone_residencial']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['telefone_comercial']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['categoria_de_cliente']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['telefone_celular']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['telefone_0800']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['insc_estadual']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['CNPJ']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['RG']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['insc_municipal']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['PIS']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['site']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['email']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['historico']."</td>";
              }
            }
        ?>
      </div>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Estrutura da table:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O formato que utilizei para tentar mostrar toda a informação do usuário é experimental, não há problema se existir uma forma melhor de fazer este processedimento.

Desculpe se pareceu confuso, tentei ser o mais claro possivel.

Desde já, obrigado pela paciência!

Comment: infelizmente tu vai ter que debugar para achar o problema eu tentaria dar uns var_dump nesse codigo começando pelo $row!

Comment: Seria interessante se você usasse ajax, que o carregamento ficaria mais rápido.

Comment: @Lodi Vou tentar, valeu pela dica

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus Não sei bem como faria isso mas vou ver como funciona ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, eu tava com preguiça de fazer uma tabela parecida, e também não tenho afinidade com mysqli, pois só uso PDO,mas eu acho que se você der umas ajustadas, fica excelente.

Esta é a sua lista de usuários:

```
<div class="row" id="realTimeContents myGroup">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="scrollable">
            <table class="table table-striped table-dark text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>Nome</td>
                        <td>CPF/CNPJ</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT id, nome, cpf FROM registro";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
                    $queryResults = mysqli_num_rows ($result);

                    if ($queryResults > 0) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td scope='row'><?= $row['id']; ?></td>
                                <td class= 'click' id="<?= $row['id']; ?>"><?= $row['nome']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $row['CPF']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <div class='collapse' id='teste_<?= $row['id']; ?>'>

                                </div>

                                <?php
                                ;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".click").click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajax.php,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    $("#teste_" + id).empty();
                    $("#teste_" + id).append(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

e esta `ajax.php` seria a página que executa a busca pelo resto das informações e jogaria no #teste_`id`:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "SELECT id, nome FROM registro where id =" . $id;
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fecth_array ($result);
//adapte o sql pra pq eu sei usar o mysqli então deve ter erro de sintaxe
?>
<td><?= $row['nome']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['CPF']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['data_de_nascimento']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['numero_de_cadastro']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['CEP']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['numero']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['bairro']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['endereço']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['cidade']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['complemento']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['uf']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['telefone_residencial']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['telefone_comercial']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['categoria_de_cliente']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['telefone_celular']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['telefone_0800']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['insc_estadual']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['CNPJ']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['RG']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['insc_municipal']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['PIS']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['site']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['email']; ?>  </td>
<td><?= $row['historico']; ?>  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar a div collpase no primeiro while assim:

```
<div class="row" id="realTimeContents myGroup">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="scrollable">
            <table class="table table-striped table-dark text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>Nome</td>
                        <td>CPF/CNPJ</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM registro";
                        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
                        $queryResults = mysqli_num_rows ($result);

                        if ($queryResults > 0) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope='row'>".$row['id']."</td>
                                    <td><a class='' data-toggle='collapse' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='teste' href='#teste_". $row['id'] ."'</a></td>
                                    <td>".$row['CPF']."</td>
                                </tr>
                              <div class='collapse' id='teste_". $row['id'] ."'>
                                    <td>".$row['nome']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['CPF']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['data_de_nascimento']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['numero_de_cadastro']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['CEP']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['numero']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['bairro']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['endereço']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['cidade']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['complemento']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['uf']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['telefone_residencial']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['telefone_comercial']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['categoria_de_cliente']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['telefone_celular']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['telefone_0800']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['insc_estadual']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['CNPJ']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['RG']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['insc_municipal']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['PIS']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['site']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['email']."</td>
                                    <td>".$row['historico']."</td>
                              </div>


                            ";
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basta colocar um identifacador no id da div collapse para linkar todas as div geradas na consulta do banco

Comment: Aqui a função de collapse não está funcionando, os dados ficam "travados" na tela e assim o botão para esconder não funciona.